# Nested set JSON to dropdown in laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, nested, dropdown

I have some problems with Nested Set...

When i do this:

```
$selects = Category::defaultOrder()->withDepth()->get()->toTree();
```

I get this JSON: https://pastebin.com/Cw4TbWyA

What i want to have:

```
Collection {#196 ▼
  #items: array:7 [▼
    1 => "123"
    4 => "- test2"
    6 => "- test4"
    2 => "1234"
    5 => "- test3"
    7 => "-- testtest"
    3 => "test1"
  ]
}
```

Or any other way to fill dropdown correctly. I'm using laravel if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx for answers, but i've found a little bit easier solution:

```
$items = Category::withDepth()->defaultOrder()->get();

$list = array();

foreach ($items as $item) {

    $list[$item->id] = str_repeat('-', $item->depth) . $item->name;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_walk_recursive to create new array of names from your existing json. Try the following:

```
$nameArray = array();
$items = json_decode($itemsJson); 
array_walk_recursive($items, 'getName'); 

function getName(&$item, $key)
{
    if($key == 'name')
    $nameArray[] = $item; 
}

echo '<pre>';
echo json_encode($nameArray);
```

Use array_walk_recursive($items, array($this, 'getName')); if using in a php frameworks controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$categories = Category::defaultOrder()->withDepth()->get()->toTree();

$traverse = function ($categories, $prefix = '-') use (&$traverse) {
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        echo PHP_EOL.$prefix.' '.$category->name;

        $traverse($category->children, $prefix.'-');
    }
};

$traverse($nodes);
```